# Merge Error = merging customers ... An unexpected error has occurred

Tags: netsuite, merge-conflict-resolution

Quite often now, when merging customers, I get the following error message from NetSuite:

The merge of the entity '????' was blocked for the following reasons: An unexpected error has occurred.

Any help please?

I tried copying the duplicate customer and then merging the new copy into the primary customer record = it worked ... however this is useless as none of the customer's transactions are copied over in the new copy of the customer!!!